# Azure Data Factory -Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.14.2.11

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory

I am running into an error trying to run a program thought ADF. The code runs fine on my console.The error is below.

```
Error in Activity: Unknown error in module: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.14.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.WindowsAuthenticationAzureServiceTokenProvider.<GetTokenAsync>d__5.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.WindowsAuthenticationAzureServiceTokenProvider.GetTokenAsync(String resource, String authority) at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.NonInteractiveAzureServiceTokenProviderBase.<GetTokenAsync>d__3.MoveNext() ---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.<GetAccessTokenAsyncImpl>d__14.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<PostAuthenticate>d__11.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__65.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretAsync>d__13.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at CRMEMAILLOOKUP.Lookup.<GetSecretCertificateAsync>
```

Part of my code I am retrieving a certificate from Azure Key Vault, my suspicion is this bit of code is causing the conflict. I am using Nuget packages Microsoft.Azure.Service.AppAuthentication , Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault and Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Webkey. Are these packages compatible with ADF v1 or is the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory reference error caused by these packages?

```
public static async Task<X509Certificate2> GetSecretCertificateAsync(string secretName)
        {
            var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(provider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            var secretBundle = await client.GetSecretAsync($"{secretName}").ConfigureAwait(false);
            var pfx = secretBundle.Value; var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pfx);
            var coll = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            coll.Import(bytes, null, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            return coll[3];
        }
```